# TableView NSException

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, nsexception

I am new to Swift , I am parsing my JSON by using `ObjectMapper` but I want data to be displayed in TableView.  But I have a problem:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I get it after the method `numberOfRowsInSection`. My array is not nil, array has a 2193 elements 
I do not understand why it happened

It my code for parsing JSON :

```
   let timeStamp = NSNumber(value: Date().timeIntervalSinceNow)

    var programs = [PrograToDayModel]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        super.viewDidLoad()
        let timeStamp = NSNumber(value: Date().timeIntervalSinceNow)
        self.downloadPrograms(for: timeStamp)

    }

    func downloadPrograms(for timestamp: NSNumber) {

        Alamofire.request("http://52.50.138.211:8080/ChanelAPI/programs/\(timestamp)").responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[PrograToDayModel]>) in

            let programlArray = response.result.value

            if let programlArray = programlArray {
                for program in programlArray {

                    self.programs.append(program)
                    print(program.title as Any)
                }


            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

it good i print element in console : 
[image]

my code for table:

```
    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
         print(self.programs.count as Any)
        return self.programs.count

    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProgramTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ProgramTableViewCell

        cell.title.text = self.programs[indexPath.row].title

        return cell
    }
}
```

All identifiers in place 
I using tab bar, tableView, tableViewCell
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: There must be a reason mention in the debugger. Please share that as well.

Comment: There should be more information in the debugger about that NSException. It should help.

Comment: @Umair Afzal   thats all : warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available. and my print and libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: @ Larme  thats all : warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available. and my print and libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Please make a breakpoint in `tableView(_: cellForRowAt indexPath:)` and check the return value of `dequeueReusableCell`. See if cell is not nil and if cell.text is initialized as well.

Comment: @Kie  tableView(_: cellForRowAt indexPath:)  this method is not called

Comment: Can you try to set a breakpoint for the exceptions. Maybe we can get more information this way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17802723/389007

Comment: @Kie AppDelegate signal SIGABRT and console libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) I dont found error

Comment: Too little exception info there. Have you set "OS_ACTIVITY_MODE" environment variable to 'disable'?

Comment: @Astoriaso I did it

Comment: In cellForRowAt method - Look at second line code. Create the iboutlet with different name [dont take as title]. Try it.   or change ProgramTableViewCell to UItableViewCell.

Comment: Did you set the datasource and delegate for your tableView?

Comment: @Koen so I did it

Comment: @Pavankumar I not go to this method

Comment: Which version of Swift are you using?

Comment: @koen Swift 3.0

Comment: @koen I found error : error in __connection_block_invoke_2: Connection interrupted

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000855/tableview-nsexception/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134702/discussion-between---and-koen).

Comment: @Koen it my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To identify the issue, you can just try this -

it might be a reason for that issue

So go to Main.storyboard, and right-click on View Controller at the top of the phone outline and remove any outlets with yellow flags (if any).

[image]

Comment: Do this and build the connection again to the viewController. Mine works by doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar non descriptive error when trying to initialize a `uitableviewcontroller` when trying to add a section/number of rows.  Did you register a tableview cell class? I see that you have a custom tableview cell created, so if that isn't registered with your tableview that might be causing this error.

```
   tableView.register("ProgramTableViewCell".self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ProgramTableViewCell")
```